# regex pattern in VB6

Tags: regex, vb6

I need to extract the RXXX, LXXX, and CXXX from these strings
TCK;  PCIEX16.A5 **R2.1** |TCK
TCK;  **R2.1** |TCK

here is my regex pattern code in VB6

```
myRegExp.Pattern = "\s[RLC][0-9]{1,5}.\.1"
```

but when I

```
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(" TCK; R2.1 |TCK")
```

myMatches.count is 0

and When the string is TCK;  **R20.1** |TCK

```
 myRegExp.Pattern = "\s[RLC][0-9]{1,5}.\.1"
```

correctly matches R20.1, How should i correctly implement this one using regex

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegEx pattern is fine, except an extra dot. Change RegEx pattern to

```
myRegExp.Pattern = "\s[RLC][0-9]{1,5}\.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The single dot matches any character. So your regex fails on `R2.1` because

- `[RLC][0-9]{1,5}` matches `R2`
- the dot matches `.`
- the literal dot `\.` fails to match the `1`.

This is no problem with `R20.1`, though:

- `[RLC][0-9]{1,5}` matches `R2`
- the dot matches `0`
- the literal dot `\.` matches `.`
- the literal `1` matches `1`.

Just remove the unescaped dot:

```
myRegExp.Pattern = "\s[RLC][0-9]{1,5}\.1"
```